# Is Angular Intro JS tour with route change possible

Tags: angular, intro.js

Is it possible to dynamically add steps so that IntroJS can find the element after a route change ?

Basically when a certain step is loaded, I am routing to another page

```
this.introJs.onbeforechange((obj) => {
    if (this.introJs._currentStep === 0) {
        setTimeout(() => {
               this.router.navigate(['', { outlets: { popup: ['user'] } }]);
            }, 0);
        }
```

Is it at all possible to get a workaround so that, for example, in `onChange` or something similar I can then add a new step there, so that IntroJS can find the element ?

Naturally, I can't set up all steps initially, because it won't find the elements on the new route - has anyone come up with a solution for a seamless usage of IntroJS tour ?

I did try the `this.introJs.addStep({})` function but that still executes on load so it's still too early to pick up the element in the DOM ?

thanks

Comment: @GRD thank you it was useful, but this is now more a question about how to tackle the tour when you need to route change

Comment: Thank you. So, Any route change happen then You want to show intro ? or anything else ? Means, Inside tour dialog, when I click next then route.navigate happens and then again you want to continue tour from that route ?

Comment: @yoyoma how do you solve this problem?